# Winform.MonthCalendar.Size not updating after .CalendarDimensions updated

Tags: .net, winforms, monthcalendar

I have a simple WinForm, which only contains a `WinForm.MonthCalendar` control.

Consider the following:

```
Sub New(Optional Title As String = Nothing, Optional DisplayMonths As Integer? = Nothing)

    If Title Is Nothing Then Title = "Pick a date"
    If DisplayMonths Is Nothing Then DisplayMonths = 1

    InitializeComponent()
    AdjustMonths(DisplayMonths.Value)
    Me.Text = Title

End Sub

Private Sub AdjustMonths(Count As Integer)

    Dim CalendarDim As Drawing.Size = New Drawing.Size(1, 1)
    Select Case Count
        Case 1
            'Do nothing
        Case 2
            CalendarDim.Height *= 2
        Case 3
            CalendarDim.Height *= 3
        Case 4
            CalendarDim.Height *= 2
            CalendarDim.Width *= 2
        Case 6
            CalendarDim.Width *= 2
            CalendarDim.Height *= 3
        Case 9
            CalendarDim.Height *= 3
            CalendarDim.Width *= 3
        Case 12
            CalendarDim.Height *= 3
            CalendarDim.Width *= 4
        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("Supported values are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, and 12.", NameOf(Count))
    End Select
    Me.MonthsDisplayed = Count

    Me.MonthCalendar.CalendarDimensions = CalendarDim
    'Me.Show()
    'Me.Hide()
    Me.ClientSize = Me.MonthCalendar.Size

End Sub
```

When subsequently showing the winform, it is not correctly sized unless I uncomment the `Me.Show;Me.Hide` hack, which for obvious reasons is far from ideal. I figured that this was because`Me.MonthCalendar.Size` would not return the correct size unless shown/painted. Any idea how to obtain the correct value?

I tried `Me.PerformLayout`, `Me.Refresh`, `Me.Update`, but it did not work.

Comment: Move `Me.ClientSize = Me.MonthCalendar.Size` to the `Form.Load` or `Form.Shown` event. Btw, unless you renamed your Control just for this question, don't assign a name that is the same as the class name (as in `Me.MonthCalendar`).

Comment: BTW, since it appears you have just that Control inside the Form, you can also set the `Form.AutoSize = true`, set `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink` and remove any `Margin` from the MonthCalendar, so the Form will simply size itself to the size of its content.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! What does happen between `InitializeComponent()` and `OnLoad` though? I had initially relied upon the `AutoSizeMode`, but in reality I apply an offset to the `MonthCalendar.Location` so that the form is as small as possible (a lot of space wasted by the control's built-in border).

Comment: @Jimi why is it bad to give it the same name, rather than `MonthCalendar1` for example? I find it convenient because then I know there is only one. Is it because it messes up when calling static functions?

Comment: Prone to very bad mishaps and in violation of the general [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) (quite important to enforce common naming conventions that make code easier to understand and less prone to subtle mistakes that are, sometimes, surprisingly hard to identify - consider it as the common rules of any written and/or spoken language).